# MYSQL Thread limit

Tags: mysql

1135: Can't create a new thread (errno 35); if you are not out of available memory, you can consult the manual for a possible OS-dependent bug

Hello I keep getting this error when my threads hit about 50 on my mysql server. I am running windows 2003, I have searched everywhere and I can not seem to find a solution for this error. Is their anyway to up the limit or what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article [here](http://www.haqthegibson.com/article/34) contains a solution to the same error as yours, but on a linux server. Yet I've posted it here in the hope that it serves some help. I'll keep updating my answer as soon as I get further solutions to your problem.